# Bash - disk utilization notification

Tags: bash

This script should output a warning notification for the utilization of the main disk if over 50%, but it provides no output. My disk is currently sat at 60% so it should in theory work.

I have added an else statement to identify if the loop is not working but the else statement isnt triggered.

I'm provided no error so its hard to identify where i have gone wrong specifically.

```
#!/bin/bash

df -H | grep /dev/sda2 | awk '{ printf "%d", $5}' > diskOutput.txt

input="diskOutput.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        if [ $line -gt 50 ]
        then
                up="`uptime | cut -b 1-9`"
                output="WARNING UTILISATION $line - $up"
                echo "$output"
        else
                echo "no-in"
        fi

done < $input
#rm diskOutput.txt
echo "finished"
```

Comment: Please validate your script via https://shellcheck.net

Comment: amd add a line at the top your `while` loop like `printf "#dbg:\$0=[$0]\n"` . Good luck.

Comment: Please add output of `df -H | grep /dev/sda2` to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
#!/bin/bash

df -H | grep /dev/sda2 | awk '{ printf "%d", $5}' > diskOutput.txt
echo "" >>diskOutput.txt
input="diskOutput.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        if [ $line -gt 50 ]
        then
                up="`uptime | cut -b 1-9`"
                output="WARNING UTILISATION $line - $up"
                echo "$output"
        else
                echo "no-in"
        fi

done < $input
#rm diskOutput.txt
echo "finished"
```

You are setting an internal field separator as space here.

```
while IFS= read -r line
```

But when creating file, with `%d` you are removing all char except digits.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you tell me why exactly you are appending nothing to the file before reading?

Comment: bash needs a terminator/separator for reading variable.  When you use `printf "%d"` it deletes everything except digit and code is not able to find where the string is getting terminated